# Can't prevent user from cancelling Touch ID

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

When the Touch ID alert is displayed, there is also a "Cancel" button.  I would prefer to NOT allow the user to cancel because they are prohibited from continuing any further.  1.  Is there a way to remove the "Cancel" button.  2.  If the "Cancel" button is required, how can I force the user to re-authenticate with a fingerprint?  If authenticate() is called a second time, the Touch ID API just lets them in.  There is no alternative passcode and I'd hate to have to code up yet another view controller for it.

```
func authenticate() {
    let myContext:LAContext = LAContext()
    let authError:NSErrorPointer = nil
    if (myContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: authError)) {
        myContext.evaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Press fingerprint", reply: { (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if success == true {
                log.debug("SUCCESSFUL AUTHENTICATION")
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showUI", sender: self)
                })
            }
            else {
                log.debug("FAILED AUTHENTICATION")

                self.authenticate()
            }
        })
    }
```

}

Comment: That's really a user hostile design - you may want to reconsider that from a design standpoint.

Comment: At least consider allowing fallback to passcode; and don't fall for the trap of thinking that touchID is more secure than passcode, since if you know the passcode you can enrol new fingers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dispatch your failure call to `self.authenticate` on the main queue;

```
func authenticate() {
    let myContext:LAContext = LAContext()
    let authError:NSErrorPointer = nil
    if (myContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: authError)) {
        myContext.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Press fingerprint", reply: { (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if success {
                log.debug("SUCCESSFUL AUTHENTICATION")
                DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showUI", sender: self)
                }
            }
            else {
                log.debug("FAILED AUTHENTICATION")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.authenticate()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```